# How can I get the yield of my purified immunoglobulins?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins

In order to get the yield of IgY through a set of purification steps, what method can I use?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Do you know the antigen of the Ig and can you make it and use it for assays?

Comment: Someone asked a [similar question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85205/3340) recently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use western blotting with a anti IgY secondary antibody conjungated to  a HRP (or other reporter), this method will primarily help with troubleshooting your purification and locating IgY in the different fractions and flowthroughs.

If you want to quantify, consider using an ELISA kit. Here is one such kit (https://www.antibodies-online.com/kit/1563240/IgY+ELISA+Kit/)